# How to get a number of rras sstp ports with WMI query?

Tags: wmi, wmi-query

With PowerShell I can use cmdlet `(Get-VpnServerIPsecConfiguration).SstpPorts`
But we have strict security policies, so I have to get only WMI counters with `Get-WmiObject -Query`.
I tried to google, but couldn't find a certain class for this value.

Could you help me please?